# Is it possible to leave keyboard showing behind a modal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I would like to show a transparent modal when focus is entered into a textfield, but I would like for the keyboard to remain opened behind it as I will superpose an image that relies on the keyboard being shown.

I am using Xamarin, but I can work with objetive-c as well. Right now I'm calling `PresentViewController` on the `EditingDidBegin`, but the keyboard is shown and immediately collapsed.

Is what I am asking possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the viewController that you present modally override `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` method and return NO:

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal 
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I tried it on the simulator on 6.1 and 7

Comment: Are you presenting modal view from `UINavigationController`?